Why did umar ra hit the servant?
Here it says:
وقال الطبراني في الكبير 309 – حدثنا يوسف
القاضي ثنا عمرو بن مرزوق ثنا شعبة عن سعد بن إبراهيم عن سعيد بن المسيب قال خرجت
جارية لسعد يقال لها زيرا وعليها قميص جديد فكشفتها الريح فشد عليها عمر رضي الله
عنه بالدرة وجاء سعد ليمنعه فتناوله بالدرة فذهب سعد يدعو على عمر فناوله عمر
الدرة وقال : اقتص فعفا عن عمر رضي الله عنهما.
The judge narrated: Amr ibn Marzuq told us: Shu'bah narrated from Sa'd ibn Ibrahim from Sa'id ibn al-Musayyib who said: A female servant of Sa'd, named Zira, went out wearing a new shirt. The wind blew at her so Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) struck her with his stick. Sa'd came to prevent him, so Umar struck him with the stick as well. Sa'd then intended to pray against Umar, but Umar handed him the stick and said, "Take retribution." However, Sa'd forgave Umar (may Allah be pleased with them both).
What is the fault of the servent such that umar ra struck her?

The reason why 'Umar ibn al-Khattab punished the slave girl is assessed by scholars as being that the slave girl through inappropriate clothing would cause fitna, since her shirt was easily lifted by wind.and thus exposed adornment.
Allah the Almighty said:

And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might succeed.
(24:31)

In other words, Omar believed she was complicit in exposing her adornments and punished her for it. As a leader of Muslims he is asked to modify and punish abominable matters if he found or witnessed it by his hands:

... He who amongst you sees something abominable should modify it with the help of his hand; and if he has not strength enough to do it, then he should do it with his tongue, and if he has not strength enough to do it, (even) then he should (abhor it) from his heart, and that is the least of faith.
(Sahih Muslim)

Some sources I've consulted (Arabic only):

An article refuting the claim that 'Umar ibn al-Khattab advocated unveiling see here.
A study on the personality of 'Umar ibn al-Khattab presented in different books see the relevant pages here.
A blog article on the topic of Niqab see here.

